# Fixing USB disk mount point in Fedora 18

Tags: fedora, usb, automount

I use [Bacula](http://www.bacula.org/en/) for my backups, with data spooled to one of two USB drives (the other is stored off site, and they get swapped occasionally). Currently these drives are labelled **BACKUP5** and **BACKUP6**.

Until last week I was using Fedora 17, which mounts USB drives in `/media/$LABEL`. So I just told bacula-sd that it should look for either `/media/BACKUP5` or `/media/BACKUP6`, with a little script to switch over when I swap the disks. But I've just upgraded to Fedora 18, and it now mounts USB drives in `/run/media/$USER/$LABEL`. So the mount point varies depending on who is logged in, or something.

Is there any way of telling udisks to have a special mount point for USB media labelled "BACKUP*"?

Answer (score 1):

I ran a Gnome utility (sorry, can't now remember which one) that added the following line to my /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/disk/by-label/BACKUP6 /media/BACKUP6 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
```

I have to admit, I didn't know about the /dev/disk hierarchy. It contains symbolic links to all the disk devices by label, UUID, ID and path.

Comment: I think, that utility is `gnome-disks`. I often use it to edit mount options of partitions.

Answer (score 1):

The only way of telling udisks to use another mount point it to override it using */etc/fstab*. In your case this would be by adding:

```
LABEL=BACKUP5 /mnt/backup5 auto user,noauto 0 0
LABEL=BACKUP6 /mnt/backup6 auto user,noauto 0 0
```

Attaching the disks afterwards, udisks will mount them on the mount-point specified in */etc/fstab*

Adding the fstab-option x-udisks-auth will require the user to authenticate as an administrator